# SQL - Schema Design for Child becoming Parent

Tags: sql, database-schema

How should a schema be designed to accommodate single people becoming parents in a list.

Say my fields for the people simply are.

```
 PEOPLE
__________
Primary Key
FirstName
Surname
DOB
Sex
EyeColour
Height
Deceased
```

This is fine for individuals but if individuals become parents in the group how should I define that. Creating a table as parents seems wrong because really they are People should their just be a separate table that is physically just a table defining parents yes no and using the 2 people ids as reference?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I see new structure:

```
 PEOPLE
__________
Primary Key
FirstName
Surname
DOB
Sex
EyeColour
Height
Deceased
CoupleID
```

where Couple ID should be the same within parents record.

So, when grouping by CoupleID you can define parents. When field is empty, then record is individual.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Hasan Alizada's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38140719/113794) is good enough, but here is my .02 cents for completeness sake.

```
PEOPLE
    Primary Key
    FirstName
    Surname
    DOB
    Sex
    EyeColour
    Height
    Deceased

RELATION
    PK
    Source          (FK)
    Target          (FK)
    RelationType    (probably another FK, not null)
    StartDate       (date, not null)
    EndDate         (date, null)
```

In a model like this you can correctly map other relationship types and when a given relationship ends.

Answer (score 1):

> Creating a table as parents seems wrong because really they are People should their just be a separate table that is physically just a table defining parents yes no

There is nothing wrong with this. Not all people are parents. (Since being a parent implies being a person it is helpful to declare a `FOREIGN KEY Parents (p) REFERENCES People (p)`.)

From the point of view of every table having a *predicate* (sentence template parameterized by column names) where a table holds the rows that make the predicate into a true *proposition* (statement), `People(P, ...)` holds rows where "P identifies a person ..." and `Parents(P, ...)` holds rows where "P identifies a parent...". (The foreign key says "for all ..., Parent(P, ...) implies People(P, ...).)

If you had a table `ChildOf(C, P, ...)` "C is a child of P" then you wouldn't need `Parents`, because it's equal to `SELECT p FROM ChildOf`.